# Convergence of Fourier sine and cosine series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> Discuss whether or not it is possible to have a Fourier series
>   $$a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty[a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)]$$ converge for all
>    $x$ without either  $$a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\cos(kx) \text{ or }
>  \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\sin(kx)$$ converging.

This is a problem in Bressoud's analysis book and my solution is as follows: "No, because if we let $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty[a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)]$, then the two other series are obtained by taking $\frac{f(x)\pm f(-x)}{2}$ and since $f(x)$ is convergent for all $x$ the sine and cosine series should also be convergent."

Here is the hint from the back of the book:

> If the Fourier series converges at $x=0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$
>   converges, and therefore the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$
>   are bounded.

Although I think my solution is correct (please correct me if I'm wrong) I still would like to see other solutions and in particular understand the author's hint since I can't see how the boundedness of partial sums can help.

Thanks!

Comment: does this answer help at all? Or is there something you would still like clarified?

Answer (score 2):

***1*** Proceeding by contraposition, if one of those two series $\Sigma a_i$,$\Sigma b_i$ doesn't converge (that they are absolutely convergent follows from the fact that the Fourier series converges everywhere) i.e. equivalently if one of $\Sigma a_i$,$\Sigma b_i$ have unbounded partial sums, then that implies that the partial sums of the Fourier series itself must also be unbounded (sum of limits is limit of sum) which contradicts the assumption that the Fourier series converges.

I.e. the boundedness of partial sums that you mentioned is a
    necessary condition for series convergence, hence if it fails for
    either $\Sigma a_i$,$\Sigma b_i$, then it fails for the Fourier
    series as a whole, and hence the Fourier series does not converge at
    all x.

(note that this follows because of absolute convergence of the series and the monotone/dominated convergence theorem)

***2*** Your solution is also correct. For example, if $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ is not convergent, then either f(x) or f(-x) is not convergent, which contradicts the assumption that the Fourier series converges everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! But still it is not clear to me how the solution goes. Suppose you want to show that $\sum a_k\cos kx$ is convergent. Is your approach based on assuming that $\sum a_k$ is divergent? Also, I don't see why from the divergence of $\sum a_k$ you can conclude that $\sum a_k$ has unbounded partial sums. Are you assuming that $a_k\ge 0$ for all $k$?

Comment: if it diverges, that means by the definition of divergence that it goes to either plus or minus infinity. hence the sums are unbounded. it is not possible to diverge to a finite, hence bounded, value

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

Comment: what we are trying to prove is: IF Fourier series converges, THEN both $\Sigma a_k$ and $\Sigma b_k$ converge. I showed that the contrapositive (which is logically equivalent) of this is true (IF one of $\Sigma a_k$ or $\Sigma b_k$ does not converge, ie diverges, ie has unbounded partial sums, then the Fourier series does NOT converge).

Comment: I'm still not convinced. Let $a_n=(-1)^n$. The $\sum a_n$ is divergent , but the partial sums are bounded. I hope it clarifies my objection to your solution. Also note that we want to show that $\sum a_n\cos nx$ is convergent, but it seems that you are trying to prove the convergence of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: I am being sloppy in my distinction between $\Sigma a_i$ (coefficients only) and $\Sigma a_k cos(kx)$ (orthonormal basis along with coefficients), but this is because the convergence everywhere of the Fourier series means that the convergence of $\Sigma a_i$ and $\Sigma b_i$ must be ABSOLUTE, ie not regular conditional convergence, but that the sum of the absolute values $\Sigma |a_i|$, $\Sigma |b_i|$ also converge - for any partial sum, just choose $x_{a_n}$ so that for all $1\le k\le n$,  $a_k cos(kx) = |a_k|$, likewise choose a $y_{b_n}$ such that for all $1\le k\le n$, $b_k cos(kx)=|b_k|$.

Comment: the key point is that the Fourier series converges everywhere, not just at x=0, so we have not only regular convergence but absolute convergence. Anyway if the sequence of $\frac{f(x_{a_n})+f(-x_{a_n})}{2}$ or $\frac{f(y_{b_n})-f(-y_{b_n})}{2}$ did not converge (in the ABSOLUTE sense, i.e. both lim inf or lim sup are plus or minus infinity), then this would contradict the assumption that the Fourier series converges everywhere (for every single x in R, namely including all of the $x_{a_n}$ and $y_{b_n}$). Moreover their partial sums would have to be unbounded.

Comment: also note that for all x in R and all k: $-|a_k| \le a_k cos(kx) \le |a_k|$ and $-|b_k|  \le b_k sin(kx) \le |b_k|$, i.e. the absolute convergence of the sums $\Sigma |a_i|$ and $\Sigma |b_i|$ certainly imply the convergence of the Fourier series (sufficient condition), and since the Fourier series converges EVERYWHERE we also have the reverse implication (necessary condition) as I explained above.

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow your line of reasoning. The author does not talk about the absolute convergence of $\sum a_k$. If he was assuming (the fact) that $\sum a_k$ is absolutely convergent, then the (absolute) convergence of $\sum a_k \cos(kx)$ would be immediate by a comparison test. So I'm not sure why he even mentions that the partial sums of $\sum a_k$ are bounded...

Comment: Well is it possible that he doesn't mention the absolute convergence of the $a_k$ because that is the answer to the problem and he only wanted to give a hint, not the complete solution? It is also not an assumption that they are absolutely convergent -- it is a result of the fact that the Fourier series converges everywhere, which is an incredibly strong assumption; the Fourier series usually only converges in quadratic mean, not pointwise, and if pointwise, usually only almost everywhere, not everywhere everywhere. If the convergence was only conditional, then I agree with you that the

Comment: boundedness of the partial sums would not be relevant without having proved absolute convergence, but once absolute convergence (including convergence to plus infinity) has been proved, the boundedness/unboundedness of the partial sums is the ONLY thing that matters. Again, the argument I gave above shows that the partial sums of the $\Sigma a_i$ and $\Sigma b_i$ are bounded, and hence that both of the original series converge to a unique unambiguous limit, which is necessary for the Fourier series as a whole to converge at every point.

Comment: Is there a misunderstanding about why the series have to be convergent? Just define a sequence of partial sums h(n) indexed by the $x_{a_n}$ (respectively the $y_{b_n}$). Even if the points $x_{a_n}$ (respectively $y_b{_n}$ don't converge, the sequence of partial sums h(n) (i.e. the series $\Sigma |a_i|$ or $\Sigma |b_i|$) goes to a positive value, finite if the partial sums are bounded, infinite if the partials sums are unbounded. However, the latter possibility, that the partial sums are unbounded, contradicts the assumption that the Fourier Series converges everywhere.

Comment: Since each h(n) is a partial sum of the Fourier series at $x_{a_n}$ (respectively $y_{b_n}$), and these series ($\Sigma a_k cos(k x_{a_n})$ or $\Sigma b_k sin(k y_{b_n})$) converge by the assumption that the Fourier series converges to a finite value everywhere.